# Is there a way to exclude all files with 100% or at a threshold across the board from karma-coverage text reporter results?

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine, code-coverage, karma-runner, karma-coverage

This is very picky of me, I know, but I have a large Angular application where many files are covered at 100% or pretty darn close to it, and I want to exclude those results, so I can just deal with the ones I need to and don't have all the extra noise.

I don't want to exclude files by name because if they change they may go below the OK threshold.

My `karma.conf.js` (I'm aware I may not need some of the plugins, this is a shared file by the team):

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    coverageReporter: {
      reporters: [
        {type: 'text'},
        {type: 'text-summary'},
      ]
    },
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    preprocessors: {'**/*.ts': ['coverage']},
    restartOnFileChange: true,
  });
};
```

and I'm gonna try to attach a screenshot here of my sample output in the type: 'text' coverageReporter:

[image: sample from text coverageReporter]

I've tried searching SO and karma / karma-coverage documentation, but I only can find excluding files/paths specifically by name, or updating thresholds, but the latter seems to be only for determining what colors show up. Thank you~

EDIT: And since I only have one file per directory, would also be useful to not duplicate the numbers by printing them for the directory AND the one file under it. Thinking I may just have to dig into the weeds and create a pull request or something.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can generate coverage reports in HTML format. There you will get option to sort files based on code-coverage.

[image: sample code coverage HTML report]

To enable such reports you will have to do update `coverageReporter` property in your karma configurations -

```
coverageReporter: {
    includeAllSources: true,
    dir: 'coverage/',
    reporters: [
        {type: 'text'},
        {type: 'text-summary'},
        {type: 'html', subdir: 'html/'}
      ]
    },
```

Reports will be generated within `coverage/html` folder.

Comment: Thank you for the secondary suggestion, though not exactly what I'm looking for :( - I don't think there is a way with the text reporter